# How to share custom-styled Ionic components in bit.dev

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, storybook, bit.dev

Could you please help with the following?

- We use Ionic with React in a team having 2 distinct projects.
- We need to style these Ionic components a little differently.
- I need to share these a-little-differently-styled Ionic components with another team for code re-use.
- I would like to showcase these styled Ionic components using Storybook to the UX team and say "this is how a button looks like"

To begin with I just added the styling in a css file and imported that file in the root React page.

But it would be nice to just encapsulate component + styling in a re-usable isolated component that other people can re-use without having to import custom css files.

I am thinking of :

```
import { IonButton } from "@ionic/react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const StyledIonButton = styled(IonButton)`
   // some custom css styling here
`;

const MyIonButton = () => <StyledIonButton {...props} />;
export default MyIonButton;
```

Now, I can track/export above component using e.g Bit.dev and have the other team consume it via npm-install.

However, I dislike :

a) changing the name from "IonButton" to "MyIonButton"

b) having to wrap each and every Ionic component as shown above

I would like myself and the other team to just use Ionic components in the **standard** way e.g

```
import { IonButton } from "@ionic/react";
...
<IonButton>Close</IonButton>
```

**BUT** having these base building-blocks/components styled in a certain way.

Could you please describe to me the right approach please? Many thanks for your time

Comment: Hi, I don't understand what exactly not work for you, are you tried to work with Bit and have an issue with it?   
Or your question is a philosophic question about the right way to share components between projects?

Comment: I does a little example with Ionic `explore-container` basic component and exported it to bit.dev using the ReactTypescript compiler, and then I installed it with npm in a new Ionic app and everything work well.   

Here is a link to the component I exported: https://bit.dev/joshk/ionic-test/explore-container   

If you need any help using Bit, you are welcome to join our Slack community.
https://join.slack.com/t/bit-dev-community/shared_invite/enQtNzM2NzQ3MTQzMTg3LWI2YmFmZjQwMTkxNmFmNTVkYzU2MGI2YjgwMmJlZDdkNWVhOGIzZDFlYjg4MGRmOTM4ODAxNTIxMTMwNWVhMzg

Comment: @Josh thank you for reply Josh, will have a look at Bit!